# JavaFx bindBidirectional Circle with textField

Tags: javafx, bind

I try bind circle w textfield. When I try bind circle start jumping when I try move it. Why circle jump? When circle is unbind doesn't jump and I can move it unproblematically. Please help me. Where is the problem? I add text because stack overflow block my post

```
public class BindTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setHgap(10);
        root.setVgap(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Laczenie");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        TextField textFieldX = new TextField();
        TextField textFieldY = new TextField();
        Circle circle = new Circle(12, 22, 22, Color.YELLOW);
        circle.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedHandler);
        circle.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedHandler);
        root.add(textFieldX, 1, 0);
        root.add(textFieldY, 2, 0);
        root.add(circle, 2, 2);
        circle.translateYProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            textFieldX.setText((String.valueOf(circle.getCenterX() + newValue.doubleValue())));
        });
        circle.translateYProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            textFieldY.setText((String.valueOf(circle.getCenterX() + newValue.doubleValue())));
        });
        StringConverter<Number> stringConverter = new NumberStringConverter();
        textFieldX.textProperty().bindBidirectional(circle.translateXProperty(), stringConverter);
        textFieldY.textProperty().bindBidirectional(circle.translateXProperty(), stringConverter);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
    private double coordinateX, coordinateY, orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            coordinateX = event.getSceneX();
            coordinateY = event.getSceneY();
            orgTranslateX = ((Circle) (event.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            orgTranslateY = ((Circle) (event.getSource())).getTranslateY();
        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - coordinateX;
            double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - coordinateY;
            double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
            double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;
            ((Circle) (event.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
            ((Circle) (event.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  One is a typo, you have `textFieldY` bound to `circle.translateXProperty()`, which probably causes all manner of weirdness.

More significantly, since you've bound the TextField text properties to the circle translate X & Y properties bidirectionally, you don't need the listeners.  So what's happening is that you drag the circle which triggers the listeners which triggers the bindings which move the circle which triggers the listeners which triggers the bindings...

Just delete the listeners, fix the typo and everything works.